# return a record from mysql if it only appears within the specified period but has never appeared before

Tags: mysql

```
$smaller_date = 01-01-2017
$larger_date = 01-09-2018
$mysql_colum = reg_person
```

I would like to have one SQL query to extract *$mysql_column* if it appears between `$smaller_date` and `$larger_date` but has never appeared before. It doesn't matter if `$mysql_colum`  appears several times between the periods I have specified above as long as it doesn't exist outside these periods.

At the moment I am extracting the records from mysql using

```
SELECT `person_id`
FROM **TABLENAME**
WHERE `time_of_registration` < $larger_date
  AND `time_of_registration` > $smaller_date
```

then I go back to the same table to check if it has appeared before having looped through the records returned using PHP:

```
SELECT `person_id`
FROM **TABLENAME**
WHERE `time_of_registration` < small_date
    AND person_id = Id_returned_from_previous_query;
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Cid that seems correct thanks, so does it mean there is no simpler way to write this query? My logic works well if I take the first record from the DB then use PHP to loop through as I check if the same person id has appeared before.

Comment: Can there be many records with the same `person_id` ?

Comment: Yes @Cid, person_id is just a foreign key.

Comment: This isn't explicitely said in question, that's why, as stated @Strawberry MVCE are nice, with table structure, datas examples and output examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT person_id FROM reg_encounter 
WHERE time_of_registration < $larger_date 
AND time_of_registration > $smaller_date 
AND person_id NOT IN (
     SELECT person_id FROM reg_counter 
     WHERE time_of_registration < $smaller_date
)
```

Comment: OP stated *as long as it doesn't exist outside these periods.* I suggest you to add in the subquery `WHERE time_of_registration <= $smaller_date OR time_of_registration => $larger_date`